# Can't give Gridview text another color with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this Jquery which changes the background of the row when the checkbox is checked:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("[id*=CheckBox1]").live('click', function (event) {



                if (this.checked == true) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "#6c42a6");

                }
                if (this.checked == false) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "#ffffff");
                }
            });

            $('#GridView1 tr').live('click', function (event) {
                if ($(event.target).is(':checkbox')) {
                    return;
                }

                var chkboxSelection = $(this).find('input:checkbox')[0].checked;
                if (chkboxSelection == true) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "white");
                    $(this).find('input:checkbox')[0].checked = false;  

                }
                else if (chkboxSelection == false) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "#6c42a6");
                    $(this).find('input:checkbox')[0].checked = true;

                }
            });


        });
```

This works, but I can't change the color of the text that is in the gridview. I want this because black on purple is not really visible.
I tried adding this this:

```
$(this).closest('td').css("color", "white");
```

But this does not work, even though this is the class on which the color needs to be changed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: where did you put your mentioned code line?

Comment: Here: `else if (chkboxSelection == false) {


                }`

Comment: that could be the problem - what is your `this` here? It's the `tr` containing the `td`. The jquery-function `closest` searches through this element and their ancestors, so `td` will not be found, if I guess your html-structure right.

Comment: Hi, why is the td not found? I mean the tr gets found so... Maybe I just don't understand it, but how do I solve this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `closest(..)` use `children(...)`. `closest` is searching in ancestors of an element, starting with itself - that's why it works for the `tr`. But the `td` is a child of `tr`, so closest will not find it.

Try it like this:

```
            $('#GridView1 tr').live('click', function (event) {
                if ($(event.target).is(':checkbox')) {
                    return;
                }

                var chkboxSelection = $(this).find('input:checkbox')[0].checked;
                if (chkboxSelection == true) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "white");
                    $(this).find('input:checkbox')[0].checked = false;  

                }
                else if (chkboxSelection == false) {
                    $(this).children('td').css("color", "white");
                    $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "#6c42a6");
                    $(this).find('input:checkbox')[0].checked = true;
                }
            });
```

Get familiar with the [jQuery Api](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)